# HELP hepes preparation

Tags: neuroscience, lab-techniques

I need help: I would like to prepare an HEPES solution, without using the powder. It is possible? I remember that I did it once, but maybe I'm wrong...does someone know a protocol for HEPES preparation without using a powder? thanks!!

I need It for morpholino dilutions. 5mM, ph 7.6.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the powder? If not, you can only buy stock solutions from the usual providers of lab chemicals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about biology but about preparing buffer solutions.

Answer (score 2):

HEPES is a particular chemical, not a mixture of chemicals so unless you have the ability to synthesise your own chemicals you cannot produce it without having the dry chemical preparation.